# Returning a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

i wanna ask a question about returning a list...
Facts:

TEAM(TEAMNAME,DIRECTOR,NATIOANALITY,OVERALLGOAL)

```
team (milan,allegri,italy, 8.5).
team (inter,benitez,italy,7.6).
team (barcelona,guardiola,spain,7.8).
team (realmadrid,mourinho,spain,7.2).
```

and i want to create a predicate: 
find(T,N,G) :  T is name of team, N is nationality of team and this team's overallgoal must be greater than G. and outputs must be like these:

`find([], spain,9). returns true`

`find(X, spain,6). returns X=[barcelona, realmadrid]`

i tried to do this with:

```
find(T,N,G):-find1(T,N,G),is_set(T).

find1([]).

find1([T|Ts],N,G):-team(T,_,N,Gs),Gc>G,find1(Ts).
```

it gives results but not like output above... 
if my goal is find([],spain,9). then give false...
if my goal is find(X,spain,6). then give first X=barcelona and wait for ";" after that give X=realmadrid... but i want to a list like above...

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a list of items satisfying a predicate from a database of clauses, one should use `findall` predicate. For example, your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
find(T, N, G) :- findall(X, (team(X, _, N, G0), G0 > G), T).
```

Comment: `setof/3` should rather be used here.